# Detect that user tap on screen Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to remove `UIView` from screen after user tap something except that view. (to visualize it for you I will upload sketch of my view)

[image]

And I want to remove blue `UIView` after user tap on something except buttons in this view. What should I use?

EDIT:
In blue `UIView` are two buttons and I want to remove that view when user tap on background image

I did what @yerpy told me to do but it isn't working.

```
func test(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("test")
}

func setUpBackgroundImageView() {
    self.view.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
    backgroundImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    backgroundImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    backgroundImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    backgroundImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(test(gestureRecognizer:)))
    backgroundImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    tap.delegate = self
}
```

And I also add `shouldReceiveTouch` function  to `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make the background a `UIControl` and add action to it...

Comment: But `UIControl` is slider yes?

Comment: Nope, `UIControl` is just a view to which you can connect actions in the same way as to a button (button is actually a type of `UIControl`). It's enough to just change the class of your view to `UIControl`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `UIGestureRecognizer` to the `super view` :

As you said you have image view as a background.

```
 let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped(gestureRecognizer:)))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
        tapRecognizer.delegate = self
```

Adding target action :

```
func tapped(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
       // Remove the blue view.
    }
```

And then inside `UITapGestureRecognizerDelegate` :

```
extension ViewController : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        if touch.view!.superview!.superclass! .isSubclass(of: UIButton.self) {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Hope it helps !

**EDIT**

Make sure that user can touch on the `view` by enabling : `self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true`

Comment: i have edited my question, it will work if I add `UIGestureRecognizer` to my background image?

Comment: But I don't have to do this function in `UITapGestureRecognizerDelegate` yes?

Comment: You have to implement this delegate function which will ignore sublacces of type (...)

Comment: I did what u told me to did but It isn't working, can u look on my code in answer below and help me?

Comment: What debug says in delegate method at if statement? The tap is recived, or its not ?

Comment: I made breakpoints at returns in delegate functions but code didn't hit them when I clicked on `UIImageView`

Comment: Where you call the method : `setUpBackgroundImageView` ?

Comment: In `viewDidLoad` function

Comment: Add this to the view `self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true`

Comment: Wow it works now, I have to add `backgroundImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`, thanks a lot for help :)

Comment: @K.Pilch No problem! Enjoy !

Comment: This is correct and it will work, however, I always wonder why people don't just use `UIControl`. It's simple and you can just connect everything in IB, no code needed.

Comment: @Sulthan Yeah, you are right that IB is recomended for actions. However he would like to detect action on `UIImageView`. Is that possible without `UIGestureRecognizer` ?

Comment: @yerpy The simplest way is to wrap the `UIImageView` into a `UIControl`. Lucky for us, there is already a wrapper, the `self.view`. We can just change it's class to `UIControl`.

Comment: @Sulthan That sounds amazing! Could you link some examples?

Answer (score 1):

1- Add a view below your view, let call it overlay (gray one)

2- Add your container view with all your buttons inside (green one)

3- Add a tap gesture to the overlay (drag tap to overlay view)

4- Create a @IBAction of the tap to the viewcontroller

5- Write code to hide your green view inside the @IBAction

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9Nm1.png)

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNOyf.png)

Comment: Combining tap recognizers and buttons is not wise. The recognizer will trigger even if the buttons are pressed, unless you manually exclude them in the delegate, which is not trivial.

Comment: Button touch cancel the tap event and doesn't pass it to super views. So the overlay wont trigger if you press a button. 
Will only read tap on overlay not on any other view.

Comment: That's not given. It more or less depends on the settings of the recognizer.

Comment: Not true, yes its given by default.

Comment: Actually, what usually happens is that the tap recognizer handles the event first and cancels the event on the button...

Comment: Did you read step 3? Tap recognizer is on overlay, not in the view that contain the button.
Also the correct answer is wrong. Force unwrap and applying that logic to every single view controller. Just to hide a "modal" ?

Comment: And event if Tap recognizer is in the same view as the buttons, button are above the view and handle the tap event first, returning false and not sending the event to the super views. And this is by default.

Answer (score 0):

you can use UITapGestureRecognizer for that view

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Add "tap" press gesture recognizer
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapHandler))
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        backgroundimage.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    // called by gesture recognizer
    func tapHandler(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        // handle touch down and touch up events separately
        if gesture.state == .began {

        } else if  gesture.state == .ended {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can

1. subclass with that background view, and implement an inherited method `-beganTouches:(there is another para but I forget what it is)`
2. Add a UITapGestureRecognizer to that view

Answer (score 0):

Add a giant button that covers the entire screen under all the buttons. Anytime the user presses on the giant button underneath the smaller buttons, do what you want it to do.

Not the most elegant but it works :P